# Structured CSS background: name?

Tags: html, css, background

I often found some backgrounds like this:
http://knplabs.de/bundles/knpcorporate/images/bg-intro.png

The whole page is: http://knplabs.de

How do you call such background types which have one color put a nice structure (like a carpit)?

Are they also available in other colors (white)?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using seamless tiles is a standard and very basic web design concept. You would take an image that when offset, doesn't create harsh edges. Here's a nice collection of tiles:

http://subtlepatterns.com/

Using them is fairly straight-forward too.

```
.someElement {background: url(path/to/image/bg.png);
```

I didn't pass in any more declarations, but if you wanted to use an offset background image that doesn't repeat and exists in front of a background colour, you could do something like this:

```
.someElement {background: red url(bg.png) no-repeat 20px 40px;}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was looking after such backgrounds ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it's call Patterns.

https://www.google.nl/search?aq=0&oq=pattern+bac&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pattern+background

Comment: Hi, so they don't have any extra name. Ok. I already tried patterns but I am just looking for an monocolored background with a bit structure on it

Answer (score 1):

You mean the pattern?

There are many sites with different patterns, both in color and in texture.
For example: [patterns](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/200-beautiful-seamless-patterns-perfect-for-web-design)  or [monochrome patterns](http://webtreats.mysitemyway.com/category/photoshop-resources/patterns/)

Comment: The monochrome patterns get quite near to that what I am looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

Its totally depends on your reqiurement like for which puprose you need a background.

***Like if u need background image for header so i think it should be by name of header-bg***

**If u need background image for whole website so name should be body-bg**

***If u need background image for footer so name should be footer-bg***

**Left-Nav bg, Right-Nav bg, container-bg etc**

so you can give the names like this but overall its totally depends on how we want to use those images and for which purpose we need the images.

Comment: Thats indeed a good approach but I actually mean the background itself :)